# Show for $z \in \mathbb C$ and $N \in \mathbb N$ that the summation holds true

Tags: complex-numbers, summation

Show for $z \in \mathbb C$ and $N \in \mathbb N$:

$(z-1)\sum_{k=1}^{N} \frac{z^k}{k} = \sum_{k=2}^{N} \frac{z^k}{k(k-1)}-z+ \frac{z^{N+1}}{N}$

---

My try:

$(z-1)\sum_{k=1}^{N} \frac{z^k}{k}\\ = \sum_{k=1}^{N}(z-1)* \frac{z^k}{k} \\= ((z-1)*z)+\sum_{k=2}^{N}(z-1)* \frac{z^k}{k} \\= z^2-z+\sum_{k=2}^{N}(z-1)* \frac{z^k}{k} \\= z^2-z+\sum_{k=2}^{N}\frac{z^{k+1}-z^k}{k} \\= $

How do I continue?
How do I enter a $N$ without changing the limits of my sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going the wrong direction: you try to combine terms with the same denominator. This is not what the question hints. You need to combine terms with the same exponent.

$(z-1)\sum_{k=1}^{N} \dfrac{z^k}{k} =z\sum_{k=1}^{N} \dfrac{z^k}{k} - \sum_{k=1}^{N} \dfrac{z^k}{k} = \sum_{k=1}^{N} \dfrac{z^{k+1}}{k} - \sum_{k=1}^{N} \dfrac{z^k}{k}$

In the first sum, use $m = k+1$. Notice that $m$ now varies from $2$ to $N+1$. Obtain

$\sum_{m=2}^{N+1} \dfrac{z^{m}}{m-1} - \sum_{k=1}^{N} \dfrac{z^k}{k}$

Extract not-matching terms to equalize ranges:

$\sum_{m=2}^{N} \dfrac{z^{m}}{m-1} + \dfrac{z^{N+1}}{N} - z - \sum_{k=2}^{N} \dfrac{z^k}{k}$

Now, rename $m$ to $k$ and combine the sums:

$\sum_{k=2}^{N} (\dfrac{z^{k}}{k-1} - \dfrac{z^k}{k}) + \dfrac{z^{N+1}}{N} - z$

Answer (score 0):

The left side equals $$\sum_{k=1}^{N} \frac{z^{k+1}-z^k}{k}$$
$$=-z+\frac{z^{N+1}}{N} + \sum_{k=2}^{N} z^k\big({1\over k-1}-{1\over k}\big)$$